# Bluedart shiping extension magento

Tags: magento

I have developed an online store on Magento e commerce platform. Now I need to integrate bluedart shiping module for shiping methods. Is there any way to implement/integrate it in magento?

Help would be appriciated, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Good guy [Kalpesh Mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124578/kalpesh) has developed an extension for that: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/km-shippingcarriers.html